# Can we use TypeIdentifierAttribute in .NET without COM?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

I am curious if it is possible to make 2 interfaces in .NET (either in the same assembly or in separate assemblies) that can be treated as equivalent, using the new TypeIdentifierAttribute attribute.  I have not found a way.

I've seen some stuff on the internet that suggest this eventually would be possible, but it kinda looks like the current implementation is only for COM interops.  I understand the immediate intentions for this were for embedding COM interops.  I am not dealing with COM interops.

Also, I am not interested in discussing why I would want to do this, I don't want to lead this question to other types of solutions.  Let's just say that I'm experimenting and I want to see if there is anything we can do with TypeIdentifierAttribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to both the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297.aspx), and [anecdotal evidence](http://www.mail-archive.com/castle-project-devel@googlegroups.com/msg08011.html), it is possible to make type equivalence work with standard, non-COM, interfaces.

From the documentation, it seems that you don't need the TypeIdentifierAttribute if your interfaces live in different assemblies. To have two interfaces treated as equivalent, you just need to:

1. Make sure they both have the same name, and live in the same namespace.
2. Apply the [GuidAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx) to them both, assigning them the same Guid.

Comment: Thank you, your second link led me to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2008/10/28/advances-in-net-type-system-type-equivalence-demo.aspx which had demo source code that was very helpful.

Comment: @MafuJosh, the link seems to be broken. Do you happen to still have the source code?

Comment: Sorry I don't.  And I can't find this blog archived anywhere.

Comment: The link isn't broken any longer.

Comment: The aforementioned link is now broken again, but the same post can be found under: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mshneer/advances-in-net-type-system-type-equivalence-demo